# AngularJS datepicker layout

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm working on the  AngularJS datepicker. Its working fine but the layout of the input box is not right. I'm unable to rectify it. Here is the code snippet from my HTML page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="startDate" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
            <input data-format="MMM-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My angular js code is:

```
app.controller('headerCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = '07-2013';
});

app.directive('datetimez', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: "MM-yyyy",
                viewMode: "months",
                minViewMode: "months",
                pickTime: false,
            }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the output I'm getting. I need the datepicker input box height and width to be similar to above combo box. I have used bootstrap css here. Any help? Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWAZ2i8GGFYvFCcjMM2h?p=preview) added. Click on Report Details on the left panel.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a CSS related problem. Please add your CSS Styles or create a plunker to reproduce it.

Comment: You only say 'the layout of the input box is not right', but you don't state how it should look. As @lin said it is probably a css related thing

Comment: Your HTML code looks very similar to this example: https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. As also the others said, the problem seems due to a CSS rule outside of the used bootstrap classes (unless you override them). I tried to rewrite your code with the same classes and it looks fine on my side. A plunker example would help.

Comment: Even I feel this must be some css issue. Let me add a fiddle and show you the output

Comment: Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OWAZ2i8GGFYvFCcjMM2h?p=preview) When you click on the "Report Details" on the left panel you can see the output I am getting. I think its due to the import file sequence in index.html. I need help resequencing it.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around, I came across the issue. You need to remove `position:relative` from `body`

```
body{
    /* position: relative; */
    background-image: url('../images/timesheet_back.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:150% 150vh;
}
```

Also, your datetimepicker styles are overridden by `bootstrap-combined.min.css` 
Adding this to your style should fix the problem

```
.input-append input, .input-append span{
  height:auto !important;
}
```

That should fix your problem.
Check the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IAjxHH5mb1Sk5lP3LUH1?p=preview) hope that helps.

Comment: The input box  size is still thinner like before. This is not solving my exact issue. Can you check my index.html file? The import files sequence is rigth?

Comment: your styles are being overridden by `bootstrap-combined.min.css` check my updated answer